# Problem with servlet request setAttibute and getParameter java

Tags: java, servlets

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("orden", 11);
    System.out.println("ord "+request.getParameter("orden"));//returns null
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/a.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

//Why does this happen?
```

and in my jsp is the same `result = null`

Comment: how are you accessing it in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an `attribute` and trying to get a `parameter`

```
request.setAttribute("orden", 11);
request.getAttribute("orden");
```

Answer (score 0):

attribute and parameter are different things. As you are setting attribute, use getAttribute() to get the value.

```
System.out.println("ord "+request.getAtribute("orden"));
```